# JProgressBar doesnt update in for-loop when loading images

Tags: java, swing, event-dispatch-thread, jprogressbar

I am programming a little tool to apply some filters to a large amount of images. I want to add an progressbar while loading in images.
For this i've written this simple code here:

```
            //Set up Progressbar 
            int pictureCount = 0;
            for (File file : chooser.getSelectedFile().listFiles(isImage)) {
                pictureCount++;
            }
            progressBar.setMinimum(0);
            progressBar.setMaximum(pictureCount);


            //Load all the Images and updating Progressbar
            for (File file : chooser.getSelectedFile().listFiles(isImage)) {
                BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(file);
                tilesNew.add(bi);
                progressBar.setValue(progressBar.getValue() + 1);
            }
```

Unfortunately the progressbar is only updated at the end of the loop. so it shows 0% the whole time and then directly 100% after the program has loaded all images for a few seconds.

So far I have tried to use
`frame.revalidate()`, `frame.repaint()` and `Thread.sleep()` in the loop. All without success.

Comment: `Thread.sleep(150)` didnt work

Comment: *Unfortunately the progressbar is only updated at the end of the loop* - that indicates you are executing your code on the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)`, which means the GUI can't respond to events or repaint itself until the loop is finished. You need to execute your code on a separate Thread. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Progress Bars](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html). It will show you how to use a `SwingWorker` so you don't block the EDT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used Swing for a long time,
but it seems that you are doing something wrong commonly found in any platform with GUI.

Your code seems to read large files in the *main (UI) thread*.

The UI will be updated when the main thread is not busy.
However, the main thread will be always busy while it is processing the image.

You should create a new `Thread`, which processes the files and the images, and then the created thread should pass it to the main thread to update the UI every time the `processBar` needs to be updated.

Here is some helpers in `Swing` to support multi-threading:
https://stackabuse.com/how-to-use-threads-in-java-swing/

Comment: I used the Invoke Later method discribed in your link. Worked like a charm. Pack the for loop in a new Thread. Then in there make a new thread which to invokeLater for the updating.

Comment: @Samuel I think that technically you need only one `new Thread` and two `new Runnable`s. Pack the `for` loop in a new `Runnable` which is the argument of a new `Thread`. And in there, wrap the UI-component related code (like the statement using `progressBar` or *Image-showing Swing components* or any UI components) in a new `Runnable` which is the argument of `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`.

Comment: Reading files or processing images can be done in any thread, but *UI components can be updated only in the main (UI) thread*. This is why `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` is used. The runnable in `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` will be passed to and executed in the main thread automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick demo on using a JProgressBar.

- I use a timer to emulate doing some work.
- When the progress bar is updated, the `ChangeListener` is invoked and I do a repaint.
- Make certain you aren't reading in your file and updating your progress bar while still in the EDT.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class ProgressBarDemo extends JPanel {
    JFrame frame;
    final static int WIDTH = 200;
    final static int HEIGHT = 30;

    public ProgressBarDemo() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(this);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new ProgressBarDemo().startUp();
    }

    public void startUp() {
        JProgressBar p = new JProgressBar(0, 100);

        // every 200 milliseconds, add one to the JProgressBar
        Timer t =
                new Timer(200, (ae) -> p.setValue(p.getValue() + 1));

        // invoked when the JProgressBar changes.  Calls repaint.
        p.addChangeListener((ce) -> frame.repaint());
        add(p);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        t.start();
    }
}
```